# opencv rtsp stream protocol

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I want to process and display a network rtsp stream that is created from a raspberry camera.
I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cv::VideoCapture * stream = new cv::VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.55.151:8554/");
    if (!stream->isOpened()) return -1;

    cv::namedWindow("rtsp_stream", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::Mat frame;

    while (true) {

        if (!stream->read(frame)) return -1;

        cv::imshow("rtsp_stream", frame);
        cv::waitKey(15);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

When the stream is not live, the execution of this results in:

```
[tcp @ 0xa12480] Connection to tcp://192.168.55.151:8554?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
```

Which means that the stream tries to connect with tcp. When the stream is live, the execution results in:

```
 [rtsp @ 0xb07960] method SETUP failed: 461 Client error
```

From internet research i found that the problem may be that the stream uses udp. If i change the URL to:

```
"udp://192.168.55.151:8554/"
```

Then the execution freezes in the `cv::VideoCapture("udp://192.168.55.151:8554/");`

VLC is able to open the rtsp stream. As i am given to understand, ffmpeg is used to decode the stream with opencv. When i run:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://192.168.55.151:8554/ -t 5 test.mp4
```

the stream decoding and saving is successful. 
So how can i specify the lower level protocol to be udp in the opencv code? Is there another way to do it with opencv?

EDIT: If i change the ffmpeg command to use tcp, i.e:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.55.151:8554/ -t 5 test.mp4
```

then i get the same exact error with the c++ code, 461 client error

EDIT: When the code uses the udp:// link, after some 15 seconds of freeze, the execution returns with error

Comment: unrelated to the question, use a local variable for `cv::VideoCapture` rather than a pointer (or at least a smart pointer)

Comment: "VLC is able to open the stream" - which one? "rtsp://192.168.55.151:8554/" or "udp://192.168.55.151:8554/"

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Capturing a Multicast UDP Video stream using OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015540/capturing-a-multicast-udp-video-stream-using-opencv)

Comment: @slawekwin the rtsp one

Comment: @slawekwin adding the @ in the udp link still freezes the execution in the initialization phase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was answered in the github opencv issues. 
The problem is that opencv forces ffmpeg to use a tcp connection, whereas my server uses rtp protocol(udp transport layer).
So in order to resolve the problem i changed the server to an http stream.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to github page, where the issue is discussed

Answer (score 4):

According to this merged request [in opencv repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9292), you can make FFMPEG in OpenCV to use UDP protocol by `setenv("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS", "rtsp_transport;udp", 1);`

Answer (score -4):

just try this code, it easy solve your problem

```
for(;;) {
    if(!vcap.read(image)) {
        std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
    if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
}
```