# rtsp method SETUP failed: 461 Client error

Tags: python, rtsp, opencv, rtsp-client

I am trying to read `rtsp` live stream using `python opencv`. I am getting the following errors:

```
[rtsp @ 000001f610c828a0] method SETUP failed: 461 Client error
 
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:856)
warning: rtsp://192.168.1.18:8554/cam (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:857)
```

This is the code that I have tried:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.18:8554/cam",cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
if cap.isOpened():
    cv2.namedWindow("demo", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    while True:
            ret_val, img = cap.read();
            cv2.imshow('demo',img)
            cv2.waitKey(10)
else:
    print("camera open failed")

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using `python 3.5` and `opencv 3.4.2`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047017/opencv-rtsp-stream-protocol

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"
```

It may be caused by the network protocol difference: The client defaults to TCP but the server uses UDP.